# MySQL INSERT results in duplicate key, but no duplicate exists

Tags: mysql

I have read through many entries that people have claimed to have this problem and they've solved their issue but none of their answers solve MY issue. I am using phpMyAdmin to update the email address of a user. The "user_email" field is marked as `UNIQUE`. Whenever I update the email address to his actual email, I get:

```
Duplicate entry 'user@example.com' for key 'user_email'
```

I have Analyzed, Optimized, and Repaired the table and no errors appear -- everything comes up as OK.

I have run several SQL statements to find any duplication only to find out that none exists.

I even exported the table and imported the records again. I add the indexes and try and update... duplicate entry message. Here's the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `md5_id` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `full_name` tinytext,
  `user_name` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_email` varchar(220) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_level` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `pwd` varchar(220) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `address` text COLLATE latin1_general_ci,
  `country` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tel` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `fax` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `website` text,
  `date` date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00',
  `users_ip` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `approved` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `activation_code` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `banned` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ckey` varchar(220) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ctime` varchar(220) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `location` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '9'
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=210 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `users` ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

MODIFY `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,AUTO_INCREMENT=210;
```

Even now that I have **REMOVED** the `UNIQUE` index from the 'user_email' field, the error is STILL coming up. I REALLY don't understand that (Maybe something residual...? I'm just guessing).

Picture me with wads of hair in my hands. Can anyone please help?

**UPDATE:**

Here's the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE users`
[image]

Here's the output from `SHOW INDEX FROM users`
[image]

Error message while editing:
[image]

Error message without using database name:
[image]

Output of: `SHOW CREATE TABLE proctor.users`
[image]

Comment: Please post the table structure output directly from `SHOW CREATE TABLE users` so we can see exactly what MySQL currently thinks it is. Also, verify of course that you're connected to the correct database. That is more often the cause than you'd probably believe.

Comment: that has no sense :-) If you have no index on your table. you can't get error `for key 'user_email'` provide please some proofs, like screenshots with table indexes, data values, and error message with query executed. from phpmyAdmin or any other tool you use.

Comment: Yes I agree with Alex, if you have no unique constraint then it would not throw Duplicate entry exception. Please check you table  structure using Show Create table <table-name>.

Comment: Also please post an `show index from users` to see what other indexes are there. Check if you are using the same database for all your actions (phpMyAdmin can be confusing).

Comment: @Alex : The only other index on the table is 'ID'.

Comment: and now where is your query to insert something and get error message?

Comment: so now as @MichaelBerkowski mentioned where is proof that you are using correct database? in your case `proctor`. try to query without `proctor`, just `users` I am pretty sure everything will be fine :-)

Comment: That is impossible. :-) Show please `SHOW CREATE TABLE \`proctor\`.\`users\``

Comment: @Alex : First picture in series above.

Comment: No, I can't see `proctor` database in that query. So we need to bee sure that it is correct database

Comment: @Alex : Picture added... I'm not sure what good that does, but it's there.

Comment: Sorry, but to me it seems that you do something wrong. That couldn't be true. But with no access to your mysql server I can't help.